# Split string by regex into array and filter by a function python (PRAW)

Tags: python, regex, praw

BACKGROUND:

I'm writing bot for [/r/Avoid5](https://reddit.com/r/Avoid5), which is about avoiding what is output by this JavaScript:

```
(()=>[..."RZ"].map(a=>atob(a+"Q==")))()
```

---

Anyway, now that we have that out of the way, the bot supposed to detect the uses of `e` or `E` in comments and point it out. However, there is an exception: URLS. I must allow URLS that have `e` in them (and parse only their link text, as defined by Reddit's version of Markdown) I have the PRAW comment stream setup such that it will iterate through new comments, assigning them to the variable `comment`. I must generate all the infractions, from the "phrases" of the comment defined as the characters in between one of the follow:

```
;:.,<>()[]!"'?
```

So I wrote the following array comprehension:

```
infractions = [x.strip().replace("e", "-").replace("E", "-") for x in re.split(r"[;:.,<>()\[\]!\"']", comment.body) if helpers.naughty(x)]
```

With `helpers.naughty()` being defined as:

```
def naughty(text):
    """
        Identifies whether a text string uses the letter 'e'
    """
    # Remove newlines
    text = re.sub("\n","",text)
    # Turn links into their text
    links = r'\[([^\]]+)\]\([^\)]+\)'
    comment = re.sub(links, r"\1", text, re.DOTALL)
    return ("e" in comment or "E" in comment)
```

I have determined that `helper.naughty()` gives the correct value, via much trial and error, but, regardless, here are positive and negative examples:

```
POSITIVE (returns True):
    Hello World
    [Hey, you](http://amazon.com)
    Sup Dude!
    [Hello World](http://google.com) | [Hi You](http://example)
NEGATIVE (returns False):
    Hi World
    [Hi, you](http://example.com)
    Sup Guy!
    [Hi World](http://google.com) | [Yo-Yo](http://yahoo.com)
```

The problem is herein: the bot's canned response contains several `e`s in URLS, which doesn't trigger the `helpers.naughty()` function,  but appears as several infractions in the aforementioned array comprehension.

I'm mostly a JavaScript programmer, but I am trying to dabble in other languages, so please be nice.

Many thanks,
Brendan

Comment: so what do you expect to get as the output with this `[Hi, you](http://example.com)`, you're removing the url part....`helper.naughty` would always return false, because what's left `'Hi, you'` has no `'e'` in it.

Comment: Exactly. That's the point, I don't want to match the `e`s in URLs, just their link text